# Не работает сумма элементов списка, помогите разобраться

Tags: python, input, while

Здравствуйте уважаемые.

Код:

```
def digit_checking():
        data_list=[]
        user_input=''
        while user_input!='exit':
                user_input=(input('Please enter digit and press enter,or use exit for Exit-> '))
                data_list.append(user_input)
                
        data_list.remove('exit')
        print(data_list)
        data_count=sum(data_list)/len(data_list)
        print(data_count)           


digit_checking()
```

Методом научного тыка выяснил что проблема в sum(data_list). Но никак не могу понять почему оно воспринимает то что в списке есть строка, ведь я ее уже удалил `data_list.remove('exit')`

Если сделать

```
user_input=int(input('Please enter digit and press enter,or use exit for Exit-> '))
```

Получаю

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'exit'
```

Подскажите как правильно поступать в таких случаях ? Возможно как то разделять ввод, или еще каким то другим способом работать? Я понимаю что это должно быть элементарно, но как то не могу найти как решить. Спасибо

Comment: научный тык сработал неправильно. Попробуйте использовать более подходящий научный метод. Например, читать текст ошибок.

Comment: @Эникейщик Большое спасибо. Как вы понимаете читать и понимать - разные вещи. Читать научился, проблему происходящего никак не мог понять! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно убедиться, что введенное значение может быть конвертировано в int. В противном случае(если это не exit) - сообщить об этом пользователю:

```
while True:
    user_input=(input('Please enter digit and press enter,or use exit for Exit-> '))
    if user_input == 'exit':
        break
    elif user_input.isnumeric():
        data_list.append(int(user_input))
    else:
        print(f"{user_input} is not a digit. Please try again.")
```

Comment: Все работает! Большое спасибо за хороший пример!

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь в user_input попадает строка, даже если вы вводите число. Потому что `input` всегда выдает строку.

```
user_input=(input('Please enter digit and press enter,or use exit for Exit-> '))
```

Вот здесь вы добавляете все эти строки в список.

```
data_list.append(user_input)
```

После удаления строки "exit" в списке все равно остались строки "5", "18", "3" и т.д. Да, они выглядят как числа, но не перестают быть строками.

Вот здесь вы пытаетесь найти сумму строк.

```
sum(data_list)
```

И поэтому возникает ошибка.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я думал что даже если удалить строку из списка все остальное останется числами. Оказывается это не так! Большое спасибо за объяснение !

Comment: Оно не останется числами, потому что никогда числами не было.

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то что бы например добавить только числа и что бы программа понимала что это только числа, это нужно огласить еще до добавления в список с помощью int. Большое вам спасибо!